# Memory leaks Problem in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, memory, project-management

I want to get some memory leaks in my code, how can i fix the memory leak.

```
dashboard  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[dashboard addObject:[[NSDictionary alloc]  initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"demo_1.jpg",@"pic_source",@"  Head",@"Title",nil];   // memory leaks here. 


if ( theConnection ) {
    receiveData = [[NSMutableData data] retain]; //memory leaks here.
}
```

But i have released dealloc - in[receiveData release];, but memory leaks happened. I know the retain, the count is increased, but how can i released the data properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think your leak in the line:

```
[dashboard addObject:[[NSDictionary alloc]  initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"demo_1.jpg",@"pic_source",@"  Head",@"Title",nil];
```

just change it to

```
[dashboard addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"demo_1.jpg",@"pic_source",@"  Head",@"Title",nil];
```

addObject retains the object so you can use convenience creation methods which autorelease the object they create.

and another possible leak... if you define your receiveData as a property with retain attribute you don't need to call retain explicitely. You can call `self.recieveData = [NSMutableData data]`. This will retain it. Of course you will still need to release it in dealloc.

EDIT to show the code:

```
NSMutableArray *anArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
 [sections setValue:anArray forKey:display_date];
```

Answer (score 2):

`dashboard addObject:[[NSDictionary alloc]  initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"demo_1.jpg",@"pic_source",@"  Head",@"Title",nil];`
You've called init method - then you are the owner of an object. When you've put it to the array - the retain was called too. Just call autorelease to fix the leak.

`receiveData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];` - if you will call `release` this object will be deleted when out of scope. If you will write

```
receiveData = [NSMutableData data];
```

It will be automatically deleted when out of scope

**EDIT**

If you are using methods with `init` word in them then you are the owner of such objects and they will not be deleted automatically until you'll call `release` method on them. If you don't want to own the object create it with some static method. For example:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: ... , nil];
```

It's the same as calling

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: ... , nil] autorelease];
```

Autorelease means the object will receive a `release` method when out of scope - and if it was not retained will be deleted automatically

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In this case, "            [sections setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:display_date];" //memory leaks here. How can i fix the leaks?

Comment: if you are using methods with init word - it means you are the owner of an object. For example you can call [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: ...]; Then you are not the owner. Or you can call autorelease method after init.